# Looking for counter example - compactness theorem

Tags: compactness, first-order-logic

Let $S$ be a family of sets.

We say a subset $S'\subseteq S$ is *good* if we can choose from every set $A\in S'$ a representative $x_A$ s.t.:
For every three sets $A,B,C\in S'$ it holds that $(x_A + x_B + x_C)$ mod $10 \neq 0$.

Using the compactness theorem I've shown that if all sets $A\in S$ are ***finite***, and if every finite subset $S'\subseteq S$ is *good* then $S$ is also *good*.

I've used the finite property of the elements in $S$ in my proof, but I can't think of an example where letting $S$ have infinite sets leads to a contradiction.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems to me that the fact that $S$ is a family of sets doesn't even matter. The fact that $A,B,C\in S'$ is the only property you need. I can't see how you could even use the finite sets assumption.

Comment: So you're saying it holds for infinite sets as well?

Comment: I say that it doesn't even matter that $S$ is a collection of sets. It could've been any set, and your $x_A$ is a function $f:S\to\mathbb{N}$ (or what ever range you are required), that should satisfy $f(A)+f(B)+f(C)\neq 0 \mod 10$. Whether such a function exists or not does not depend on the nature of the elements of $S$.

Answer (score 0):

I just reduced the problem of infinite sets to finite sets (all the set has to contain is the remainders from division by 10).